# How to pass Knockout.js value in controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment

I have value in knouckout js i am trying to pass it on controller or observer. what should i do? anyone can help me.

```
getSelectedValuecc: function() {
            /* jQuery(document).on("click", ".cusbtn", function (event) {
                if (!jQuery('input[name="payment[method_wallet]"]').is(':checked')) {
                var msg = "Please select any one options";
                    jQuery("#ccavneue_mssg").show();
                return false;
                }
                var radioValue = jQuery("input[name='payment[method_wallet]']:checked").val();
                //alert(radioValue);
                if(radioValue == 'paytm'){
                        jQuery("#ccavneue_mssg").hide();
                           jQuery("#cust_paytm").click(); 
                }
                if(radioValue == 'mobikwikwallet'){
                             jQuery("#ccavneue_mssg").hide();
                            jQuery("#submob").click(); 
                }
            });*/
            jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("#paytm_payment_profile_id").change(function () {
            //alert('select chnage');
            var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
            //jQuery('input[name="payment[method]"]').attr("disabled",true);
            if (selectedValue !=''){
               jQuery("#pay").show();
               jQuery("#address").show();
            }else{
                jQuery("#pay").hide();
                jQuery("#address").hide();
            }
            alert("Value: " + selectedValue);
            if(selectedValue == 'vsquare'){
               jQuery("#address").html("V Square Building 1st Lane, DwarakaNagar,Visakhapatnam-530016,AP.,India").show();
               jQuery("#paytm").click();
               return false;
            }
            if(selectedValue == 'pavanpalace'){
               jQuery("#address").html("A-1,Pavan Palace,near telugu thalli Flyover,Station Road, Dwaraka Nagar,Visakhapatnam-530016,AP.,India").show();
               jQuery("#paytm").click();
               return false;
            }
        });
    });
        //});,
    },
```

call this value on html

```
<select name="payment[method]" class="select input-text required-entry" 
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {id: getCode()+'_payment_profile_id'},
                                event:{ change: getSelectedValuecc()},
                                options: getCardList(),
                                optionsValue: 'value',
                                optionsText: 'type',
                                optionsCaption: $t('--Select Store--'),

                                ">
         </select>
```

now i am looking for pass selectedvalue in save order before observer to save this value in table.